# Смена пароля . Как получить данные

Tags: yii2, yii

у меня такая проблема. Пользователь авторизованный заходит и должен получить возможность поменять пароль, для этого я ввожу с формы старый   и новый пароль. Как мне проверить соответствие старого пароля новому. Как получить старый пароль  чтобы сравнить с новым?  В базе хранятся хэши. Фреймворк Yii

Comment: А вы не думали сравнивать то что ввел пользователь? или сравнивать хэши? разницы то собственно никакой...

Comment: Я сравниваю пароль введенный с формы новый и его сравниваю с хешем находящимся в бд. Проблема  в том, как узнать,какой текущий пароль у авторизованного пользователя

Comment: Для чего нужно знать текущий пароль?

Answer (score 0):

Берется хэш от введенного пароля и сравнивается с хэшем в базе. Это все.

Например так: `Yii::$app->security->validatePassword($password, $this->password_hash)`

Comment: Так как оно определит , какой юзер авторизован ,чтобы знать какой хеш для него сравнивать

Comment: @ДмитрийИгнатов а как это делает сейчас ваш сайт? как он определяет кто именно зашел?))))

Comment: Ввел пароль,авторизовался, зашел в системе на кнопку сменить пароль, но дальше ему нужно ввести свой пароль, который у него в бд и новый, какой он захочет. Как определить тот пароль, который сейчас находится в бд и сравнить с новым

Comment: Совершенно непонятно, в чем проблема. Есть старый пароль, новый пароль и хэши от них, а также хэш от старого пароля в базе. В чем проблема-то? Не можете сравнить два хэша?